# Error deserialising a DateTime that ASP.NET converted to JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

We have a MAUI app (although I don't think that is actually relevant) that sends data to an ASP.NET Core minimal API.

We use a common DTO (simplified)...

```cs
public record MyDto(DateTime Date);
```

The app serialises this as follows (again, simplified)...

```cs
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyDto(DateTime.Now));
```

...and sends it to the API.

The API has some middleware that grabs the incoming JSON and deserialises it...

```cs
MyDto dto = JsonHelpers.Deserialise<MyDto>(httpContext.Request.Query["data"].ToString());
```

However, this throws an exception "*The JSON value could not be converted*" because of the format of the date. The app is sending JSON that includes a date formatted as `2023-05-24T20:20:46.9351772 01:00`, which causes the deserialiser to choke.

Following many answers here, I tried a custom JSON converter, but couldn't get it to work. For example, I tried...

```cs
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?> {
  const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff zzz";

  public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
    DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
    writer.WriteStringValue(value?.ToUniversalTime().ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

However this still gives the exception. If I use this code on a manually written piece of JSON, where the date is formatted `2023-05-24T20:20:46.9351772`, then the deserialiser works fine, so it seems to be the offset that's the problem. I can't work out how to set the `Format` string to work with the offset.

According to [this page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1), `zzz` should work fine for the offset, and indeed does work fine when using `ToString()` on a date.

What puzzles me is that we have loads of DTOs in the code that include a `DateTime` property, and are successfully deserialised in API endpoints. I don't understand why this one should be any different.

What puzzles me further is that all of this should be handled by the framework. Surely `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` should be able to work with the output of `JsonSerializer.Serialize`?

Anyone able to advise? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

1. You are not using the format when deserializing, so use it. For example:

```cs
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?> {
    const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz";

    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(value?.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
public record MyDto([property: JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]DateTime? Date);
```

```cs
var myDto = new MyDto(DateTime.Now);
var ser = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myDto);
var deserialize = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDto>(ser);
Console.WriteLine(deserialize.Date == myDto.Date); // true
```

2. Your format does not represent correctly the provided sample string. It should be something like this - `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz` (`T` added between date and time, `HH` used instead of 'hh')
3. It seems that `zzz` requires sign (`+`/`-`) - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier) so you might need to fix the input (for example using regex replace to fix it):

```cs
var myDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDto>("""
{
   "Date": "2023-05-24T20:20:46.9351772 +01:00"
}
""");

public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime> {
    const string Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz";

    // TODO - check for empty/null strings, use TryParse
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        throw new JsonException();
}
```

P.S.

Actually if you change space to `+`/'-' sign in the original string it looks like a valid date in the [ISO 8601](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) format which should work out of the box:

```cs
var myDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDto>("""
{
   "Date": "2023-05-24T20:20:46.9351772+01:00"
}
""");

public record MyDto(DateTime? Date);
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that the problem was the code that was generating the JSON, but your answer was very useful in understanding what's going on. Thanks again.